# Ext js 4 animating styles

Tags: animation, css, extjs, extjs4.1

Suppose I want to rotate an Ext js 4 panel 180 degrees around Y Axis. 
(For an example - click the square labeled '3D rotate' at [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_3dtransforms.asp))

I was trying to use Ext.js element.animate method and provided the 'to' attribute with new css attribute but with no success:

```
button1.animate({
       duration: 2000,
        to:{
            style :{
                '-webkit-transform' : 'rotateY(180deg)'
            }
        }
    });
```

I am pretty sure there is a good way of doing it. Does anyone know of a resource I can see examples for changing style with animation on Ext js 4?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AbstractComponent's` animate method [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent) (and code) show it exclusively handles x,y, top, left, width and height.

## Using Ext.util.CSS.updateRule

You can define for your button this css rule:

```
#btn {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}​
```

Then perform something like this:

```
var i = 0;                        
setInterval(function(){
    i++;
    i = i % 360;
    Ext.util.CSS.updateRule('#btn', "-webkit-transform", "rotate(" + i + "deg)" );
 }, 10);
```

You can see something similar working in [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/kxqAq/).

## Applying a css animated class

By calling:

```
button1.addCls( 'fadeIn' );
```

With the corresponding css (generated by [compass](http://compass-style.org/)):

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from { opacity: 0; }  
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

.fadeIn {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease-in 1;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease-in 1;
  -o-animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease-in 1;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease-in 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: Doing fadeIn is much easier than what you did. My problem is with styles such as replacing the rotateY degrees which I cannot pronounce with 'from' and 'to'. Or, to ask it more directly: How would you replace - not the opacity but - the -webkit-transform attribute?

Comment: [Ext.util.CSS.updateRule()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.CSS-method-updateRule) may help you.